# Flat tables enabled only for one store view

Tags: eav, flat-catalog

We have 2 store view: one "fr" and one "en".

We keep getting an undefined method on "addAttributeToSelect" but only for one store view.

I've used "var_dump" to display the result of this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                            ->addCategoryFilter($_categoryTemp);

    var_dump($_productCollection); exit;
```

In french we get :

```
protected '_flatEnabled' => 
array (size=1)
  2 => boolean false
```

In english we get :

```
  protected '_flatEnabled' => 
array (size=1)
  1 => boolean true
```

I know that flat tables are enable for the whole website. Not per store view.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe the index is not built for that store?

Comment: How would I go about building the index for a specific store ? I usually run : php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall

Comment: That should do it.